# Manga where MC uses his own lightning magic on his mind to change his memories and personality

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I don't remember much of it but the Main Character (MC) uses lightning magic on his mind in order to wipe memories and change his personality. When he gets older he does it again out of despair and almost kills himself, but he is saved by a spirit and taken to their world to rehabilitate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Mostly black and white

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Outcast Adventurer's Second Chance ~Training in the Fairy World to Forge a Place to Belong~](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tsuihou-bokensha-no-yarinaoshi-yousei-kai-de-kitae-naoshite-jibun-no-ibasho-wo-tsukuru)*

> "Glen, your bad reputation is dragging the party down. We're kicking you out today." A party of adventurers formed from childhood friends. The day after a promotion exam, Glen was summoned to the guild and expelled by the party leader. ... This is a story about an adventurer trying to regain the things he has lost. Those who abandoned him will wallow in grief, while he moves forward with his new companions.

After being kicked out of his party, Glen zaps himself a second time and is rescued by fairies, and spends time recuperating in the land of the fairies. He had met them the first time he used the lightning magic on himself to alter his personality.

[image: Brain surgery preparation]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have started and read over 200 different manga and wanted to see if this one had any updates.