# Manga where the MC is kicked out of party and uses electric magic on his head to forget things

Tags: story-identification, manga

It is a manga where the MC is kicked out of party and uses electric magic on his head to forget things. He is saved by the spirit queen and was taken to the spirit realm. The manga is in black and white.
Additional Information the mc is given new eyes  from the spirit queen, he and the old party are orphans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Outcast Adventurer's Second Chance ~Training in the Fairy World to Forge a Place to Belong~](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tsuihou-bokensha-no-yarinaoshi-yousei-kai-de-kitae-naoshite-jibun-no-ibasho-wo-tsukuru)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261938).

> "Glen, your bad reputation is dragging the party down. We're kicking you out today." A party of adventurers formed from childhood friends. The day after a promotion exam, Glen was summoned to the guild and expelled by the party leader. ... This is a story about an adventurer trying to regain the things he has lost. Those who abandoned him will wallow in grief, while he moves forward with his new companions.

After being kicked out of his party, Glen zaps himself a second time and is rescued by fairies, and spends time recuperating in the land of the fairies. He had met them the first time he used the lightning magic on himself to alter his personality.

[image: Brain surgery preparation]

At the end of the first chapter, he is rescued by the queen of the fairies and is given a special magic eye.

[image]